# How to implement API PATCH request on the backend for an outing approval system?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I have created an Outing Approval System using MERN Stack, I have implemented the following code to set leaveStatus to "Approved" but the changes do not remain on refreshing my page. There is no issue with PATCH request through postman.

**Mongoose Schema leaveStatus Snippet**

```
leaveStatus : {
        type : String,
        default : 'Not Approved',
        enum : [
            'Approved',
            'Not Approved']
    }
```

**Frontend Outing Approval Function Snippet:**

```
const approveOuting = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('api/outings/' + outing._id, {
            method: 'PATCH'
        }) 

        if (response.ok) {
            const json = await response.json()
            var updatedJson = {...json, leaveStatus : "Approved"}
            dispatch({type: 'PATCH_OUTING', payload: updatedJson})
        }
    }
```

**Outings Reducer Snippet:**

```
case 'PATCH_OUTING' :
            // Find the index of the outing to be updated
            const outingIndex = state.outings.findIndex((outing) => outing._id === action.payload._id);

            // Create a copy of the outings array with the updated outing
            const updatedOutings = [...state.outings];
            updatedOutings[outingIndex] = action.payload;

            return {
                outings: updatedOutings
            };
```

I created a temp var to hold the current json and edit the leaveStatus to approved and send it as my payload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a route on the backend that handles the PATCH request. This route should update the `leaveStatus` field in your MongoDB database. In your backend code, you might have something like:

```
// Import necessary modules
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const Outing = require('../models/outing'); // Import your Mongoose model

// Define the PATCH route for updating outing leaveStatus
router.patch('/outings/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const outing = await Outing.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      { leaveStatus: 'Approved' }, // Update the leaveStatus to 'Approved'
      { new: true } // Return the updated document
    );

    if (!outing) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Outing not found' });
    }

    res.json(outing); // Return the updated outing
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is my function for the patch request, wouldn't your function make every patch request change the leaveStatus to approve?

`const updateOuting = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params

    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({error : 'No such outing'})
    }

    const outing = await Outing.findByIdAndUpdate({_id : id}, {
        ...req.body
    })

    if (!outing) {
        return res.status(400).json({error : 'No such outing'})
    }

    res.status(200).json(outing)
}`